# proposition of borel-cantelli lemma

Tags: almost-everywhere

I know by the Borel-Cantelli lemma that for all $\epsilon > 0, \  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n|>\epsilon)<\infty \Rightarrow X_n \xrightarrow{a.e.} 0$. But, how can I prove that the if and only if condition holds, which means that also holds that if $X_n \xrightarrow{a.e.} 0 \Rightarrow$, for all $\epsilon > 0,\ \  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X_n|>\epsilon)<\infty$. I know that by another proposition of this lemma holds that $X_n \xrightarrow{a.e.} 0 \Leftrightarrow$, $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)= 0$, but I need to add that the sum of this probabilities greater than $\epsilon$ is less than $\infty$?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true without further assumptions.  If all you know is that
$X_n \to 0$ almost surely, then $P(|X_n| > \epsilon)$ can go to $0$ arbitrarily slowly.

EDIT: For example, let $U$ have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and 
$X_n = 1$ if $U < t_n$, $0$ otherwise, where $t_n \to 0+$.  Thus
if $0 < \epsilon < 1$, $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = t_n$.  We do have
$X_n \to 0$ almost surely, but $t_n$ can go to $0$ arbitrarily slowly,
and in particular $\sum_{n=1}^\infty t_n$ need not converge.

EDIT: If the $X_n$ are independent, you can use the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result).

Comment: could you be so kind as to explain yourself a little further, please? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sorry, and if I assume that are independent, can I prove that if $X_n \xrightarrow{a.e.}0\  \Rightarrow \sum P(|X_n|>\epsilon)<\infty$??? thank you very much